# Ctrl-w closes my Chrome window

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, chrome

As I become more used to Emacs, I mix it with other applications quite a lot. For killing some text in Chrome browser windows, I repeatedly type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>, and close chrome windows and lost my unfinished input.

Is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> a window-closing shortcut for Chrome only, or for majority applications in Ubuntu 12.04?

I opened Chrome's settings, but didn't find that setting.

Comment: I'm not sure of the origin, but if I'm not mistaken, Ctrl+w is the close-tab shortcut in Firefox and Opera as well. I was under the impression that it came from them.

Answer (score 7):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> is the shortcut to close the current document or tab in many applications. I don't know where it originated (at a guess, Mac), but it's become a standard in most major environments, including [Gnome](https://wiki.gnome.org/Design/OS/KeyboardShortcuts), [KDE](http://docs.kde.org/stable/en/kde-runtime/fundamentals/kbd.html), [OSX](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1343) and [Microsoft Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290938).

Mnemonic: <kbd>W</kbd> is next to <kbd>Q</kbd> on QWERTY keyboards; <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> is for ***q**uit*, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> is for a lesser form of quitting. Some applications don't have a keyboard shortcut to quit, though, on the assumption that this isn't something users commonly do (typically you close documents, not applications).

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to cut (kill) the selection is an Emacs shortcut. The de facto standard (Gnome, KDE, OSX, Windows and many more) is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> (mnemonic: X as in a cross to suppress something), with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to **c**opy and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste (mnemonic: downward-facing arrow). You can enable [`cua-mode`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/CUA-Bindings.html) in Emacs to activate these shortcuts, however the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> CUA shortcuts clash awkwardly with Emacs's; to use an Emacs `C-c` or `C-x` prefix in CUA mode while the selection is active, you need to press the second key or repeat the prefix quickly (and to use `C-c C-c` or `C-x C-x`, you need to press the key three times).

Answer (score 2):

It's application-dependent... I'm not sure one can say the majority has that shortcut, since it's unlikely one has used the majority of applications. As an example, `xpdf` uses `Ctrl+W` to close the current file. I'm haunted by the `Ctrl+F`, `Ctrl+W`, `/` for "search" confusion. I wish there was a *de facto* standard on *nix for that, and other things such as `-r` vs `-R` for recursive. Well, the world isn't perfect.

I think you can install an extension to override Chrome's shortcuts. A quick search led to [this one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shortcut-manager/mgjjeipcdnnjhgodgjpfkffcejoljijf). Perhaps the window manager shortcuts could override Chrome's too? Haven't tried, and it probably depends on the window manager. I guess an extension is the way to go if you want to override that behavior - or maybe change it on emacs.

Comment: This is so annoying. You can indeed change shortcuts, but Ctrl+W is one of the few you can't.

Everytime I want to cut/paste in overleaf I end up closing the window.

Comment: (From Overleaf) We've never found a solution for Chrome, but for FireFox there is an extension that you can use to prevent FireFox from using C-w to close the tab: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/s3menu-wizard/